# Update QTreeWidget during runtime

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

I'm new to Qt and I was trying to update the data of a `QTreeWidget`. The `QTreeWidget` is created by Qt Creator (using drag and drop).
The `QTreeWidget` I created is as below.

```
1
    a   A  
    b   A
    c   C
2
    x   X
    y   Y
    z   Z
```

I need to update the 2nd column of 2nd row A to B in run-time using code.

```
b   A
```

to

```
b   B
```

Anyone knows how to update the value?
As I created the QTreeWidget in ui designer. The Widget name is treeWidget.

Comment: QSreejith T   Read this page: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [`QTreeWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html) and [`QTreeWidgetItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html) documentation, you can do it as follows:

```
treeWidget->topLevelItem(0)->child(1)->setText(1, "B")
```

Comment: Thank you for the support. Now it's working as expected.